# Why should energy change with mass?

Tags: kinematics, mass, velocity

At void, an object with velocity v, mass m collides with an object with the same mass m at rest. Let's assume that they were connected to each other(the instant after the collision). then it would be double the mass and half the velocity
$E = \frac{1}{2}2m(\frac{v}{2})^2 = \frac{1}{4}mv^2$

There is no PE in the object.

Why would it lose KE and Where does the KE go?